# How to convert all date objects from a list into datetime objects

Tags: python, list, date

I have this list:

```
myList = [datetime.date(2021, 1, 1), datetime.date(2021, 2, 1), datetime.date(2021, 3, 1)]
```

I want to use a loop to replace all the `date` objects in this list with `datetime` objects. Any solutions?

Comment: Do you know how to change one date to datetime? https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-list-comprehension

Comment: no i am asking that too

Comment: If date is in `d`, then `datetime.datetime(d.year, d.month, d.day)`

Answer (score 0):

Just use `datetime` constructor:

```py
import datetime

l1 = [datetime.date(2021, 1, 1), datetime.date(2021, 2, 1), datetime.date(2021, 3, 1)]
l2 = [
    datetime.datetime(year=d.year, month=d.month, day=d.day)
    for d in l1
]

print(l2)
```

Answer (score 0):

[datetime.datetime.combine](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine) can be used to create a `datetime.datetime` from a `datetime.date` and a `datetime.time`. Pass `datetime.time.min` to get the start of the day

```
import datetime
myList = [datetime.date(2021, 1, 1), datetime.date(2021, 2, 1), datetime.date(2021, 3, 1)]

result = [datetime.datetime.combine(d, datetime.time.min) for d in myList]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
date_list = []
for date in myList:
  date_list.append(datetime.datetime(date.year, date.month, date.day))
```

if you want to use a for loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use `help(datetime.date)` and `help(datetime.datetime)` to find that `date` has attributes for year, month and day, and that `datetime.datetime` takes those values when its created. So make a list comprehension that does that

```
>>> import datetime
>>> myList = [datetime.date(2021, 1, 1), datetime.date(2021, 2, 1), datetime.date(2021, 3, 1)]
>>> newList = [datetime.datetime(d.year, d.month, d.day) for d in myList]
>>> newList
[datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 0, 0)]
```